# moviePlayer setOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationPortrait not work?

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

I got a problem that it hasn't change to portrait mode when using the following code:

```
NSString *url = @"http://abc.com/movie.3gp";

MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill; // seen nothing change when comment this line

if([moviePlayer respondsToSelector:@selector(setOrientation:animated:)])
    [moviePlayer setOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationPortrait animated:NO];

[moviePlayer play];
```

Is my code problem? anyone can solve my problem or any alternative?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is there any particular reason you expect this code to work?  `MPMoviePlayerController` isn't documented as having a `setOrientation` method...

I don't think there's a way to make this happen.

Comment: It's because I am finding solution for portrait mode and some of answer in this site said this method seen work, so I'm asking help for this, or I may misunderstanding the answer from other post.